# Installation of Exchange 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, exchange-2010

I am preparing to setup a new install of Exchange 2010 can anyone point me to a good resource to help me do this?

The reason for the install is our current exchange 2003 is 8 years old and needs to be replaced.

I have a couple of servers that I can use as a test environment, I have created a brand new domain and I want to install and configure exchange 2010 on the other, but I don't want it to interfere with our existing exchange 2003 install. The plan is to get it setup and working and then start moving mailboxes across.

Any help or resources on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The best resource is TechNet, however there are countless other guides on the internet. I would recommend you don't use a new domain - that's hassle you don't need, and Exchange 2003 and 2010 co-exist absolutely fine.

Some quick links:

- [Exchange 2003 - Planning Roadmap for Upgrade and Coexistence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998186.aspx)
- [Checklist: Upgrading from Exchange 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332309.aspx)
- [Rapid transition guide from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010](http://milindn.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/rapid-transition-guide-from-exchange-2003-to-exchange-2010.pdf) (PDF)
- [Your Guide to a Successful Exchange Server 2010 Migration Project](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2003-2010-migration-guide)

Comment: We need a new domain to fix some of our other problems, but thanks for the links

Comment: Maybe you could create new questions on Server Fault for your problems? Moving to a new domain *will* complicate things for you, and it's best you're absolutely sure before you go down that road.